# Most pythonic way to preform sub-section analysis on a data frame multiple times?

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I have a large time-series dataframe at the second interval, and I need to preform some analysis on every grouping of 0-59 seconds.
This is then used to be a feature in a different time-series dataframe by using the floor of the sub-section

I feel like I'm missing something basic, but unsure of the wording to get it right.

ex:

```
timestamp,close
2021-06-01 00:00:00,37282.0
2021-06-01 00:00:01,37282.0
2021-06-01 00:00:02,37285.0
2021-06-01 00:00:03,37283.0
2021-06-01 00:00:04,37281.0
2021-06-01 00:00:05,37278.0
2021-06-01 00:00:06,37275.0
2021-06-01 00:00:07,37263.0
2021-06-01 00:00:08,37264.0
2021-06-01 00:00:09,37259.0
...
2021-06-01 00:00:59,37260.0
2021-06-02 00:01:00,37261.0 --> new analysis starts here
2021-06-02 00:01:01,37262.0
# and repeat
```

My current implementation works, but I have a feeling is a *really* bad way of doing it.

```
df['last_update_hxro'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.timestamp.second == 59 else 0, axis=1)
df['hxro_close'] = df[df['last_update_hxro']==1].close
df['next_hxro_close'] = df['hxro_close'].shift(-60)
df['hxro_result'] = df[df['last_update_hxro']==1].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.next_hxro_close > x.hxro_close else 0, axis=1)
df['trade_number'] = df.last_update_hxro.cumsum() - df.last_update_hxro
unique_trades = df.trade_number.unique()

for x in unique_trades:
    temp_df = btc_df[btc_df['trade_number']==x]
    new_df = generate_sub_min_features(temp_df)
    feature_df = feature_df.append(new_df)

def generate_sub_min_features(full_df):
    # do stuff here and return a series of length 1, with the minute floor of the subsection as the key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set timestamp as index:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S")
df.set_index('timestamp')
```

Then group by hour and save each dataframe in a list:

```
groups = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H'))]
```

Comment: I changed ```freq='T'``` to work for my example, but this help speed up my results. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IMO, any pandas solution which includes a loop could be done better.

I feel I may be a little lost on your ask without a basic example, but it sounds like you're looking for a simple [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) or [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)?

### Example

Here's a sample using a df loaded with the distinct seconds from 1/1/21 - 1/2/21, paired with random integers from 0 - 10. We'll take the average of every minute.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_time = pd.DataFrame(
    {'val': np.random.randint(0,10, size=(60 * 60 * 24) + 1)},
    index=pd.date_range('1/1/2021', '1/2/2021', freq='S')
)

df_mean = df_time.resample('T').apply(lambda x: x.mean())

print(df_mean)
```

Returns...

```
                          val
2021-01-01 00:00:00  4.566667
2021-01-01 00:01:00  5.000000
2021-01-01 00:02:00  4.316667
2021-01-01 00:03:00  4.800000
2021-01-01 00:04:00  4.533333
...                       ...
2021-01-01 23:56:00  4.916667
2021-01-01 23:57:00  4.450000
2021-01-01 23:58:00  4.883333
2021-01-01 23:59:00  4.316667
2021-01-02 00:00:00  2.000000
```

### Notes

Note the use of `T` here to define the "minute" portion of the datetime flags in the index. Read more about [Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases). Also the use of the `resample()` method since our timeseries also acts as the index. `groupby()` would have also been valid here with a slightly different approach in case our datetime information was not our index.

### Customization

In application, one would replace the contents of `lambda()` with whatever function you'd like to apply to each distinct group of line items which share a truncated datetime-minute.

Comment: I needed to do some analysis on the second interval that is lost if I resample the data. So I think a groupby is better for this specific example